# Efficient dictionary creation from pandas dataframe for looping

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, for-loop

I have the following dataframe:

```
V1 = ['a','a','c','d']
V2 = ['test1', 'test2'  , 'test3'  , 'test4' ]
        
df = pd.DataFrame({'V1':V1,'V2':V2})
print(df.head())

V1     V2
a    test1 
a    test2
c    test3 
d    test4
```

I would like to loop over it as follow:

```
for [unique element in v1 column]:
    for [corresponding elements in V2]:
```

I thought about building a dictionary with the following format:

```
    dic = { 'a':['test1', 'test2'], 'c':['test3'] , 'd':['test4'] }

for elt in dic:
    for i in dic[elt]:
```

Is there a better way/more efficient way to do this? If not how can I build such a dictionary efficiently?

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option to build the dictionary using pandas would be:

```
dic = pd.Series(V2, index=V1).groupby(level=0).agg(list).to_dict()
```

output: `{'a': ['test1', 'test2'], 'c': ['test3'], 'd': ['test4']}`

With classical python, use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict
dic = defaultdict(list)
for k,v in zip(V1, V2):
    dic[k].append(v)
    
dict(dic)
# {'a': ['test1', 'test2'], 'c': ['test3'], 'd': ['test4']}
```

To loop over your values from the initial dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'V1':V1,'V2':V2})

for name, d in df.groupby('V1'):
    print(f'entering group {name}')
    for value in d['V2']:
        print(f' value {value}')
```

output:

```
entering group a
 value test1
 value test2
entering group c
 value test3
entering group d
 value test4
```

Answer (score 2):

You can aggregate `list` by [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) and then `Series` convert to dictionary by [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
 #your DataFrame
 df = pd.DataFrame({'V1':V1,'V2':V2})

 d = df.groupby('V1')['V2'].agg(list).to_dict()
```

Answer (score 2):

Just using python, no pandas! Below code take only `O(n)` time, so this is pretty fast.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

V1 = ['a','a','c','d']
V2 = ['test1', 'test2'  , 'test3'  , 'test4' ]

my_dict = defaultdict(list)

for x, y in zip(V1, V2):
    my_dict[x].append(y)

print(my_dict)
```

output

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'a': ['test1', 'test2'], 'c': ['test3'], 'd': ['test4']})
```

You can use other pandas `group by` solutions if you think you have very large datasets otherwise simple & efficient solutions like above is good enough for general use cases.

Comment: why did you copy my answer? :/

Comment: @mozway - No way! I did not copy

Comment: Do you mean that you used the `f'entering group {name}'` etc. bit of code purely by chance? This is exactly the same :/ So close that I almost edited your answer thinking it was mine…

Comment: oh! I am very sorry. I understood now ! I thought you were referring to code!

Comment: Well to be fair, I also had posted the `defaultdict` solution before, that's why it was quite troubling to see your answer to evolve to look like mine. I don't mind you reusing my example, but in this case, might be better to leave a note

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243689/discussion-between-sam-and-mozway).